# How do I hide ListView on click?

Tags: java, android, listview, hide

In my XML file I have:

```
<ListView  android:id="android:id/list" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:visibility="visible" 

  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:fadingEdge="none">


</ListView>
```

My Java code:

```
public OnClickListener teamlisten = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
       // do something when the button is clicked

     View list = (View)findViewById(R.id.myviewId);
      list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

     }
 };
```

As you can see I'm trying to set my listview to invisible, the problem is I can't get it to appear in my R.java so I can't seem to make it invisible. I only want the listview to turn invisible when a button is pressed.

Any help on this one would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` within your `ListActivity`.

This is how it looks inside your code:

```
public OnClickListener teamlisten = new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
};
```

Comment: I have observed strange behavior that this does not work form onCreate(). Another one in a looooooong list od android bugs.